# Can't call a variable from another file

Tags: python-3.x

I have two files. The first file, we'll call it "a.py". The second, "b.py".

Here's an example of "a.py":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

CHOOSE = input ('''
         \033[1;35m choose 1 or 2:\033[0m
         1)tom
         2)jack
''')

a = 666
b = "bbb"
def f():
    print("this is a test")
    return "function"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if CHOOSE == '1':
        username = 'tom'
        print(username)

    elif CHOOSE == '2':
        username = 'jack'
        print(username)

    else:
        print('wrong choice,scipt is exit...')
```

Here's an example of "b.py":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

import a
from a import b,f,CHOOSE,username

a = a.a
f()
print(b,a,CHOOSE,username)
```

when i run `python b.py`,system feedback error:
[image]

wherem am i wrong?how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this snippet:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if CHOOSE == '1':
        username = 'tom'
        print(username)

    elif CHOOSE == '2':
        username = 'jack'
        print(username)

    else:
        print('wrong choice,scipt is exit...')
```

Will get executed only if the `a.py` run as the main python file not imported from other module, so `username` will not be defined so you can not import it. Here how to fix it:

`a.py`:

```
...

def foo(CHOOSE):
    if CHOOSE == '1':
        username = 'tom'

    elif CHOOSE == '2':
        username = 'jack'

    else:
        username = None

    return username
```

`b.py`:

```
from a import foo
CHOOSE = input ('''
         \033[1;35m choose 1 or 2:\033[0m
         1)tom
         2)jack
''')

username = foo(CHOOSE)
if username:
    print(username)
else:
    print('Wrong choice')
```

*Explanation*: First you need to extract the code that calculate the name into something reusable. Function are meant for code reusability so I defined one which take one parameter and it return the corresponding value. This function is then used (imported then invoked) in `b.py`.

Usually `if __name__ == '__main__':` is placed in the module that you consider your entry-point, so if you want to use it maybe `b.py` is a better place.

Answer (score 0):

The block `if __name__ == '__main__'` only triggers if the script is run with `a.py` being the *main* module (e.g. you ran it using the command `python a.py`). If anything else was used as the main module, and `a` was imported, then this condition is not met and the code inside of it does not run.

The variable `username` is created and added to `a`'s namespace in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block. When you do `python b.py`, the code inside this block does not execute, and as a result `username` never gets added to the namespace. So when you try to import it, immediately after loading the file `a`, you get an error saying that the `'username'` doesn't exist - it was never created.

Comment: thank you ,but how to explain b.py get "CHOOSE" from a.py successfully?